# netbeans - preview html within IDE , split view?

Tags: html, ide, netbeans, netbeans6.7, netbeans-plugins

I have installed the latest version of netbeans and its working.. I have opened an html file but i don't see where i can preview it..

Does it support HTML preview inside the IDE?

Do i need a plugin?

I would like to view in design mode at least so i can design in the ide ...

All i see is pure html ...

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this feature is in Netbeans as of 6.7 I'm afraid. There is CSS preview, but I assume that falls short of the full preview you require. You can preview it directly in the browser by selecting "view" in the context menu, but that again is nowhere near the full preview which you require.

Searching [plugins.netbeans.org](http://plugins.netbeans.org) also proves fruitless.

Answer (score 9):

Download NetBeans for PHP, open an HTML file and you will see [image]

Comment: +1. You have to install two plugins: "Web Preview" and "Embedded Browser UI - XUL Runner". Then, in Tools>Options>General you have to select "Embedded Mozilla Browser" as the default web browser for Netbeans.

Comment: Working fine, but needs to install the modules for browser preview in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

"Web Preview" and "Embedded Browser UI - XUL Runner" solution **is only working at Windows** systems. My solution is using an external HTML WYSIWYG Editor **for Mac OS X**. There are some nice free/open source HTML interface builders:

http://www.kompozer.net/

http://ckeditor.com/

http://www.w3.org/Amaya/

Alternatively you can use HTML palette + Netbeans HTML Source editor. Click Window + Palette. At the right hand side palette will be opened which contains basic HTML elements. You can drag & drop elements to your source code as visual designers but it only creates code. This function can also help you for some basic tasks.[image]